# reading Json as an object MVC

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I want to refer a json from a file on .net MVC.
The JSON is under Content file.
How can I do that?
(The example here doesn't work..)

```
var url1 = "../../Content/FreeJsonPL.json";
$.getJSON(url1, function (data2) {}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Firts, I'd recommend to check your routings, maybe some route handles your request. Secondly, second parameter consumes function which handles requested JSON file, maybe you get it, but just not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write controller to get file from server below is an example which will return Json result. In below code you need parse Json file like Usermodel in GetUsersHugeData function

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Web.Mvc;  
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;  
using JsonResultDemo.Models;  

namespace JsonResultDemo.Controllers  
{  
    public class JsonDemoController : Controller  
    {          
        /// <summary>  
        /// Get the huge list of Users  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <returns></returns>  
        public JsonResult GetUsersHugeList()  
        {  
            var users = GetUsersHugeData();  
            return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }  

       /// <summary>  
        /// Get the huge list of users  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <returns></returns>  
        private List<UserModel> GetUsersHugeData()  
        {  
            var usersList = new List<UserModel>();  
            UserModel user;  
            for (int i = 1; i < 51000; i++)  
            {  
                user = new UserModel  
                {  
                    UserId = i,  
                    UserName = "User-"+i,  
                    Company = "Company-"+i  
                };  
                usersList.Add(user);  
            }  

            return usersList;  
        }  

        /// <summary>  
        /// Override the Json Result with Max integer JSON lenght  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="data">Data</param>  
        /// <param name="contentType">Content Type</param>  
        /// <param name="contentEncoding">Content Encoding</param>  
        /// <param name="behavior">Behavior</param>  
        /// <returns>As JsonResult</returns>  
        protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType,  
            Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)  
        {  
            return new JsonResult()  
            {  
                Data = data,  
                ContentType = contentType,  
                ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,  
                JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,  
                MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue  
            };  
        }  

        #endregion  
    }  
}
```

Then you need to write your get request client side code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://domain_name/api/controller_name/method_name", false);
xhr.send();
```